# How do I synchronize change in a UILabel text with a related animation?

Tags: ios, core-animation, synchronous, cakeyframeanimation

I have an animation of a drinking glass filling up from empty to full, using CAKeyframeAnimation. The animation works perfectly fine.

I need to update a UILabel with the percentage corresponding to the fullness of the glass, i.e. it will read "0%" when the animation begins, and "100%" when it ends.

The keyframe animation runs for 5 seconds. I don't see a good way of updating this label. I can think of two options:

1. starting another thread and running a polling-type loop that updates the text at the cost of processing power.
2. break down the animation into 100 parts and use CABasicAnimation to update the text and then proceed with the next bit of glass animation.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can remember _some_ WWDC video one or maybe two years ago that did somethings similar but I can't remember which one... Their demo app did something like water plants. Hopefully someone remembers which one I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out - I searched the WWDC sessions for 2011 and 2010, but didn't find anything about plants. I'll keep looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either a NSTImer or dispatch_after() blocks to update the label at some scheduled interval:

```
// assume an ivar "NSTimer *myTimer" and "int count", initially 0

// fires 20 times, so update is 0.05
myTimer = NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES

- (void)updateLabel:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  ++count;
  if(count >= 20) {
     [timer invalidate];
  }
  CGFloat percent += 0.05;
  myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about NSTimer. I hope it will work if the animation duration is reduced, the documentation says it's only reliable for 10-20 calls per second. But I think it will work just fine for the current use case of 5 seconds.

Comment: People will have a really hard time reading the label if you update it too often - play with and get the affect you like. If you are happy with this answer it would be great if you clicked on the check icon next to it so as to accept it (we get points for an accepted answer, in case you didn't know).

Comment: I agree, and I have set it up for 100ms intervals, where the code determines the current percentage based on the elapsed time, and not on the number of calls to the NSTimer scheduled selector, so it's not very sensitive to gaps or rapid calls. It looks just fine, most likely because CA is also animating a change in size, making it update very smoothly :)